# How to replace default square icon when custom icon-font is loading

Tags: html, css, web, fonts, font-face

Application need to assign lot of icons and while icons are assigned i seen for while squares. Is any chance how to prevent that ? And replace default call back for square icon? Before any custom icons are loaded.

Comment: add some code, or something which will tell us where could be the problem

Comment: Its not about some piece of code is hard to simulate that. But if you add non-existing icon, result will be empty square. Is any change to replace that icon of empty square? Best if square can be replaced before other things are loaded.

Comment: i think You can check in JS is icon null or not, and then when its null replace this by other img

Comment: Here is link: http://codepen.io/lececil/pen/bZkaaG
You need to clear cache in browser and turn on simulation of downloading on 4G for example. In small time before icons are rendered and downloaded they are just empty squares.

Answer (score 0):

Converts font files to a data string on compilation and injects that into the code, so once the code is loaded the fonts will be there and the browser doesn't need to request them separately. Nowadays browsers don't wait for fonts to load so that they can display the content asap not the original styles.css